# Java Calculating salary

Tags: java

I am clocking start and stop for workingtime, hh:mm.
Salary is 150 / hour.

I get the indata:

```
hour1 = keyboard.nextInt();
minute1 = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();

hour2 = keyboard.nextInt();
minute2 = keyboard.nextInt();

Total hours:
totHours = hour2 - hour1;

Total minutes:
totMinutes = (minute2 + minute1)/60;

totTime = totHours + totMinutes;
totSalary = totTime*Salary;
```

It doesnt work. The result just counts the differens between hour2 and hour1 and ignores the minutes.

Comment: Is `totMinutes` an integer? Integer cannot store decimal places and will only store whole numbers.

Comment: You should really use the Calendar class the JVM provides. Otherwise you have to deal with daylightsaving, leap years and alike yourself.

Comment: Please show a minimal, complete and verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: BTW, why are you using `+` for the minutes?

Comment: Try using `double` for all those values (even if you use `nextInt` to read them) so that the `/60` can give you a meaningful result, and swap the `+` for `-`, then it _might_ work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your hours and minutes are of type `int`; at least you are using `nextInt` to get the values, and I can reproduce your problem that way.

```
int hour1 = 12;
int minute1 = 45;
int hour2 = 14;
int minute2 = 30;

double totHours = hour2 - hour1;
double totMinutes = (minute2 + minute1)/60; // 1.0
double totTime = totHours + totMinutes;     // 3.0
```

This is because if both the dividend and the divisor are integers, then `/` will also produce an integer, i.e. the floor of the actual division. Divide by `60.0`, then it works. Also, use `-`, not `+`. And of course make sure to store the result in a `double`.

```
double totMinutes = (minute2 - minute1)/60.0; // -0.25
double totTime = totHours + totMinutes;       // 1.75
```

However, as pointed out in comments, it might be wiser to use a library for date/time calculations.